# How to add an HTML Tag Attribute in GoLang Template

Tags: go, go-templates

I have the following code:

```
{{range . }}
    <td {{ if not .IsDisabled }}onclick="return toggle_active($(this))"{{ end }}>
      [x]
    </td>
{{end}}
```

This works, it puts the onclick event like it should.

However, if I try to create the `onclick` event dynamically as a string (either in the template, or as a Go function, it doesn't work.

Example:

```
{{$clickEvent := "return toggle_active($(this));"}}
<td {{$clickEvent}}>[x]</td>
```

Or:

```
func (d TemplateObject) Click() string {
    return "onclick=\"toggle_active($(this))\""
}

<td {{.Click}}>[x]</td>
```

It renders it like this in the HTML:

[image]

If I don't put it in the `<tag>` itself `<td>{{$ClickEvent}}</td>` it prints it as a string.

How can I get the attribute to render correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do

```
func (d TemplateObject) Click() template.HTMLAttr {
    return "onclick=\"toggle_active($(this))\""
}
```

so that it knows the string is safe to use as an attribute

https://pkg.go.dev/html/template#HTMLAttr

> HTMLAttr encapsulates an HTML attribute from a trusted source, for example,  `dir="ltr"`.
> Use of this type presents a security risk: the encapsulated content should come from a trusted source, as it will be included verbatim in the template output.

Comment: Wow, so simple. That was it. Appreciate the quick response